# Return value from JSON in Scala (akka and spray)

Tags: scala, akka

I don't know what to say. Second day straight I try to get the value from JSON object juggling many Scala libraries. This one is `Akka` with `spray`. I try to save where on earth id to variable and return it from function/method. I does not matter for me if it will be `Future` or not, but I'm stuck at this statement `int =  for {lel <- ss} yield lel`. Whatever I try, I always get the initial value of `int` wherever it is a class, case class, Future[Int] or Int. Please advice.

```
    scala> def queryLocation(location: String): Future[Int] = {
     | var int: Any = Future{0} ; val locUri = Uri("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/").withQuery(Uri.Query("query" -> location))
     | 
     | val req = HttpRequest(uri = locUri, method = HttpMethods.GET);val respFuture = Http().singleRequest(req);
     | respFuture.onComplete{
     | case Success(value) => {
     | val r = Unmarshal(value).to[Seq[Search]]
     | val ss = for { reich <- r  } yield reich(0).woeid
     | int =  for {lel <- ss} yield lel
     | }
     | }
     | int.asInstanceOf[Future[Int]] }
       respFuture.onComplete{
                            ^
On line 5: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
       It would fail on the following input: Failure(_)
def queryLocation(location: String): scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> Await.result(queryLocation("Warsaw"), 1.second)
val res221: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a Future which is eagerly executed:

```
var int: Any = Future{0}
```

I see different problems here:

1. Don´t use var. A Future is an asynchronous computation and there is no sense in mutating anything in there.
2. Why do you declare a variable as Any?. It is a Future.

And this for-comprehension:

```
int =  for {lel <- ss} yield lel
```

looks bad. And maybe it is because Scala future is not referentially transparent. So avoid that. If you want to deserialize the content of the response just use **map**:

```
val future = HttpRequest(uri = locUri, method = HttpMethods.GET).map(content => Unmarshal(value))

Await.result(future, 1.second)
```

Comment: You should `execute request`, and unpack incoming json to type  e.g. `case class Type {member: String}` using `.to[Type]`